# PHP equivalent to Python's enumerate()?

Tags: php, python, iteration

In Python I can write:

```
for i, val in enumerate(lst):
    print i, val
```

The only way I know how to do this in PHP is:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count(lst); $i++){
    echo "$i $val\n";
}
```

Is there a cleaner way in PHP?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Don't trust PHP arrays, they are like Python dicts. If you want safe code consider this:

```
<?php
$lst = array('a', 'b', 'c');

// Removed a value to prove that keys are preserved
unset($lst[1]);

// So this wont work
foreach ($lst as $i => $val) {
        echo "$i $val \n";
}

echo "\n";

// Use array_values to reset the keys instead
foreach (array_values($lst) as $i => $val) {
        echo "$i $val \n";
}
?>
```

-

```
0 a 
2 c 

0 a 
1 c
```

Comment: +1: the second example using `array_values` is basically what `enumerate` does (of course `enumerate` also accepts iterators, so you'd need a bit more code to handle that case)...

Comment: In addition to @ircmaxell's comment, PHP has `iterator_to_array($iterator, false)` which will create an array from the iterator.  `false` tells it to not use the iterator's keys, but to use an incrementing value like `array_values` generates.

Comment: Documentation link for the lazy ones: [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php). There is also [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) which does the same for the keys of an associate array.

Answer (score 11):

Use [`foreach`](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
foreach ($lst as $i => $val) {
    echo $i, $val;
}
```

Comment: Only works if the array is not associative and/or the keys are continuous.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Huh?  `foreach` works for all `Traversable` objects and arrays.  What are you referring to?

Comment: @ircmaxell: Python's `enumerate()` counts from a start value (default `0`) to `#listElements`. You on the other hand are just outputting the keys of the array. If the array is associative, then it is not equivalent to the `enumerate()` function. See Tomasz answer.

Answer (score 1):

In python enumerate has `start` argument,  to define start value of enumeration.

My solution for this in php is:

```
function enumerate(array $array, $start = 0)
{
    $end = count($array) -1 + $start;

    return array_combine(range($start, $end), $array);
}

var_dump(enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c'], 6000));
```

The output is:

```
array(3) {
  [6000]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [6001]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [6002]=>
  string(1) "c"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the index, key, and value, equivalent to this Python:

```
for ii, (key, value) in enumerate(my_dict.items()):
    print ii
    print key
    print value
```

You can create an enumerate function in PHP that wraps your objects. It's not meant to be efficient (it pre-iterates and collects everything) but it can be syntactically convenient.

```
function enumerate($array) {
    class IterObject {
        public $index;
        public $key;
        public $value;
    }

    $collect = array();
    $ii = 0;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $iter = new IterObject();
        $iter->index = $ii;
        $iter->key = $key;
        $iter->value = $value;
        array_push($collect, $iter);
        $ii++;
    }
    return $collect;
}
```

**Example usage:**

```
foreach (enumerate($my_array) as $iter) {
    echo $iter->index;
    echo $iter->key;
    echo $iter->value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `foreach` loop of PHP:

```
 foreach($lst as $i => $val)
       echo $i.$val;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you were looking  for the [range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function.

One use case could be the pagination where (assume) you have 150 items and you want to show 10 items per page so you have 15 links. So to create those links you can use:

```
    $curpage=3;$links=15;$perpage=10; //assuming.

    <?php foreach(range(1,$links) as $i):?>
        <?php if($i==$curpage):?>
             <li class="active"><a class="active"><?=$i?></a><li>
        <?php else:?>
             <li><a href="paging_url"><?=$i?></a><li>
        <?php endif ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the introduction of closures in PHP 5.3 you can also write the following:

```
array_map(function($i,$e) { /* */ }, range(0, count($lst)-1), $lst);
```

Of course this only works if the array is stored in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the helper function:

```
function enumerate(array &$array, callable $fn) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($array as $key => &$value)
        $fn($i++, $key, $value);
}
```

And I use it as follows:

```
enumerate($array, function ($i, $key, &$value) use (&$something)  {
    ...
});
```

The downside may be that you have to pass external variables that you want to use inside the loop through the use (...) directive.